# ¡Como Cargar una imagen a Tkinter y redimensionarla?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy tratando de reducir una imagen cargada desde tkinter pero no me esta resultando, algún héroe que pueda ayudarme a resolver este problema?

```
def load(self):
        global imagen
        file_name=filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Subir',filetypes=[('GIF FILES', '*.png')])  
        image= Image.open(file_name)
        image= image.resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        photo = PhotoImage(image) 
        self.LabelImagen.config(image=photo)
```

Comment: Freddy, estás recibiendo algún error? Podrías dar más detalles? Un código de ejemplo mínimo y funcional, también ayudaría.

Comment: Ni un error, solo no aparece la imagen, por favor podrías remodelar mi código e intentarlo hacer a tu manera?

Answer (score 0):

Freddy, como no publicaste un trozo de código completo y verificable, tuve que asumir algunas cosas, espero haber acertado.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk as itk

class Ventana():
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = Tk()
        self.v.geometry("300x300+500+300")
        boton = Button(self.v, text="Clic", command=self.load)
        img = itk.PhotoImage(file="uno.png")
        self.lbl_imagen = Label(self.v, image=img)
        boton.place(x=10, y=10)
        self.lbl_imagen.place(x=10, y=40)

        self.v.mainloop()

    def load(self):
        file_name=filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Subir', filetypes=[('PNG FILES', '*.png')])

        pil_img = Image.open(file_name)
        wh = int(pil_img.width/2)
        pil_img = pil_img.resize((wh, wh), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        pil_img = itk.PhotoImage(pil_img)

        self.lbl_imagen.config(image=pil_img)
        self.lbl_imagen.image=pil_img  # Recomendación de la documentación de PhotoImage

ven = Ventana()
```

La clave de todo está en el método **PhotoImage**, ya que existen al menos dos de ellos, uno directamente en **tkinter**, y otro dentro de Pillow (PIL), es por ello que se realiza el siguiente *import*:

> from PIL import Image, ImageTk as itk